# Как сверстать такую стрелку?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня только есть мысль что нужно делать через псевдоэлементы бордерами, убираю 2 стороны...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например так:

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -10x;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <span>30%</span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут есть два варианта:

1) **Без испольования картинки:** Этот вариант лучше, так как чем меньше картинок – тем лучше. Просто создаешь элемент, например span, делаешь фикс. ширину, блочность. Абсолютное выравнивание. В нем будет размер скидки по центру. И 1 псевдо-элемент с треугольником. Туториал по созданию: http://htmlbook.ru/blog/treugolniki-cherez-css. Делаешь нужных размеров и позиционируешь под самим блоком span.

2) **С изображением:** Просто делаешь тот же span под размер стрелки и заливаешь его этой самой стрелкой в png. Padding-ом двигаешь саму скидку. Еще раз – я бы данный метод не советовал. Лишний вес сайта и лишнее подключение(если ты не юзаешь спрайты).